# Afferent coupling in SONAR

Tags: java, testing, sonarqube, code-metrics

I want to find in a given Java project, the classes with the highest [afferent coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_package_metrics).

I know that the metric is available in SONAR when you

- drill down to a class from the dashboard, or
- when you drill down package by package in the components view.

**What's the quickest way to find this information within SONAR?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to define a filter in Sonar which only includes files. If you define a dashboard which contains this filter you can simply order the files by afferent couplings if you've added this column.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, Sonar provides a link to the **Package Tangle** metric on the dashboard of a given project.

Comment: The package tangle metric is useful to cut dependencies between packages, it provides a the afferent coupling for any 2 packages you select. 
What I had in mind instead was getting the afferent coupling of all java classes in my project (accross all packages) so as to find those that are more used (referenced) to concentrate there my tests.
Is that possible through the package tangle view ?